# Trouble testing @Output using Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am having trouble testing an `@Output` parameter in my Jasmine test for Angular 5. It appears that the button click is not happening, since the event emitter is not triggered.

My component looks like this:

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component( {
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html'
} )
export class SearchComponent {
  @Output()
  citySearch: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
  city;

  constructor() {
  }

  onSubmit( formValue ) {
    this.citySearch.emit(formValue.value.city);
  }
}
```

The template:

```
<form #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
  <div>
    <input id="city"
           name="city"
           placeholder="City"
           type="text"
           [ngModel]="city"
           required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

...and finally, the test:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { SearchComponent } from './search.component';

describe( 'SearchComponent', () => {
  let component: SearchComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SearchComponent>;
  let cityInput: DebugElement;
  let submitButton: DebugElement;

  beforeEach( async( () => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule( {
      declarations: [ SearchComponent ],
      imports: [ FormsModule ],
      schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
    } )
           .compileComponents();

  } ) );

  beforeEach( () => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent( SearchComponent );
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    cityInput = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css( 'input' ) );
    submitButton = fixture.debugElement.query( By.css( 'button' ) );
    fixture.detectChanges();
  } );

  it( 'should create', () => {
    expect( component ).toBeTruthy();
  } );

  it( 'should emit Liverpool in the @Output', () => {
    let city;
    cityInput.nativeElement.value = 'Liverpool';

    component.citySearch.subscribe( ( value ) => city = value );

    submitButton.triggerEventHandler( 'click', null );

    expect( city ).toBe( 'Liverpool' );
  } );
} );
```

It appears that the `submitButton.triggerEventHandler( 'click', null );` is not actually doing anything, since the `subscribe` does not receive any events. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does triggering event **submit** on **form** changes anything?

Comment: Nope. I tried `form.triggerEventHandler( 'submit', null )` too but that had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I end up with something like this:

```
it('should emit Liverpool in the @Output', () => {
    let city;
    component.city = 'Liverpool';
    fixture.detectChanges();

    component.citySearch.subscribe((value) => city = value);

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        submitButton.nativeElement.click();

        expect(city).toBe('Liverpool');
    });
});
```

`whenStable` is probably necessary here because of asynchronous activity related with that `ngForm` **but I'm not sure about this**. I work more often with reactive forms but is not the case here, anyway if you would like to change it I can help.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, that does not work. I tried variations with `async()`, `tick`, and `detectChanged()` but no joy.

Comment: I actually think it's the button click that is not working, but it's hard to tell if `city = value` is working.

Comment: It's strange because I recreated component that you have and test passes. Right now I don't have access to that code but afternoon I will post it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `expect` statement should go inside the `subscribe` block of `city`.
2. And also you can simply click the button using `submitButton.nativeElement.click();` as @Buczkowski has shown in his answer.
3. Use `async`, since you are verifying asynchronous data in your test or else your test will run out soon.
4. Dispatch event after setting value to input `cityInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`

So the final code :

```
it( 'should emit Liverpool in the @Output', async(() => {
    let city;
    cityInput.nativeElement.value = 'Liverpool';
    cityInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

    component.citySearch.subscribe((value) => {
                  city = value ;
                  expect(city).toBe('Liverpool');
               });

    submitButton.nativeElement.click();
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm afraid it doesn't work. I get `Expected undefined to be 'Liverpool'.` And what does `cityInput.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));` do?

Comment: Does your onSubmit function get called? Did you try logging?

Comment: `dispatchEvent(new Event('input'))` tells angular that a value of input has been changed. This is required within angular jasmine test. Because angular will not automatically detect the value change of an input.

Comment: No, my `onSubmit()` method is not being called. So it's a problem with the `submitButton.nativeElement.click();`?

Comment: I read little more about `triggerEventHandler`. Could you try this `submitButton.triggerEventHandler( 'click', {target : submitButton.nativeElement} )`. But I dont understand why `submitButton.nativeElement.click();` is not working

Comment: Nope, still not triggering the click! Or the click isn't leading to a form submission; one of the two!